# Read info from string

Tags: python, numpy

If I have an input like this:

```
a = np.array([['31-01-2017 15:02:13.870916 120 0.3'],
              ['31-01-2017 15:02:15.890922 100 0.5'],
            ....])
```

Is there a way to access the information?

For example, the first is the timestamp, the second is a value (120) and the third another value (0.3)

Comment: Use [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)? to split by spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Split it from right on `' '` with max splits equal to 2.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([['31-01-2017 15:02:13.870916 120 0.3'],
              ['31-01-2017 15:02:15.890922 100 0.5'],
             ])

print a[0][0].rsplit(' ', 2)
```

Output:

```
['31-01-2017 15:02:13.870916', '120', '0.3']
```

### List of lists:

```
l = [['31-01-2017 15:02:13.870916 120 0.3'], ['31-01-2017 15:02:15.890922 100 0.5'] ]
print [a[0].rsplit(' ', 2) for a in l]
```

Output:

```
[['31-01-2017 15:02:13.870916', '120', '0.3'], ['31-01-2017 15:02:15.890922', '100', '0.5']]
```

Comment: Nice!I didn't know,thanks!Can you tell me a nice way (using numpy) to access the elements of the array?For example (not using numpy)  `for r in a:   for c in a:  print(a[r][c].rsplit(' ', 2))`.(upvoted)

Comment: Thanks!So, using numpy I can use the same approach ,instead of having a list of lists, I use the numpy array .I mean , I am wondering if there is a more "numpy" way to do this.

Comment: @George  Oh you want to access those. I didn't get your question. Wait I'll modify in sometime.

Comment: @George  You can access them in variables like so: `for b in a:
    v1, v2, v3 = b[0].rsplit(' ', 2)` `v1` will contain datetime, `v2` second element, `v3` third.